# Change the main database to Test when using Pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest

Help me solve the problem

Here is my settings.py:

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": ENV.MYSQL_DSN.path.lstrip("/"),
        "USER": ENV.MYSQL_DSN.user,
        "PASSWORD": ENV.MYSQL_DSN.password,
        "HOST": ENV.MYSQL_DSN.host,
        "PORT": ENV.MYSQL_DSN.port,
    },
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_db',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Here is my test_api.py:

```py
import json

import pytest
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    return APIClient()


def test_proxys(api_client):
    url = reverse("gelet")
    response = api_client.get(url)

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert response["Content-Type"] == "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    assert b"<html>" in response.content


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_generate_report(api_client):
    url = reverse("generate_report")
    data = {
        "dates": "01/01/2021 - 03/01/2021",
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    }
    response = api_client.post(
        url,
        data=json.dumps(data),
        content_type="application/json",
    )

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert response.json() == {"status": "started"}
```

How can I force autotests to use the test database test?
It is important for me to understand which method can work. Please advise something.

If there is an option with separate creation of a Postgres database, for example, this is also a suitable option

I tried to use sqlite3 by creating it directly in the program code, but something didn’t work out

```py
import sqlite3


def run_sql(sql):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.executescript(sql)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    run_sql('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name TEXT,
            age INTEGER
        )''')
    settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = 'the_copied_db'
    settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
    settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = 'test_db'
    settings.DATABASES['default']['USER'] = 'username'
    settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'] = 'password'
    settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = 'localhost'
    settings.DATABASES['default']['PORT'] = '5432'
    yield
```

Comment: I find it a bit bizarre to run tests on a PostgreSQL database when your production database is MySQL. While the Django ORM aims to be dialect-invariant, it is not entirely, so the database technology *can* have an impact on queries, and therefore testing it with a different database could hide errors or introduce ones not in production.

Comment: thanks for the comment
But the point is not the database, but how to get it to be used
If necessary, I will change it to a test MySql

Answer (score 0):

Typically what you do is create an extra settings file, like `test_settings.py` that reimports all items from the `settings.py` file, and then changes a few settings, like:

```
# test_settings.py

from settings import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': ENV.MYSQL_DSN.path.lstrip('/'),
        'USER': ENV.MYSQL_DSN.user,
        'PASSWORD': ENV.MYSQL_DSN.password,
        'HOST': ENV.MYSQL_DSN.host,
        'PORT': ENV.MYSQL_DSN.port,
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': ENV.MYSQL_DSN.path.lstrip('/'),
        },
    }
}
```

Then you can run the tests with:

```
python manage.py test --settings=path.to.test_settings
```

That being said, I find it a bit bizarre to run tests on a PostgreSQL database when your production database is MySQL. While the Django ORM aims to be dialect-invariant, it is not entirely, so the database technology *can* have an impact on queries, and therefore testing it with a different database could hide errors or introduce ones not in production.

Comment: @HardWorker: they use pytest *under the hood*, but they did some patching on it. So you use `manage.py` test, and it will eventually spin up pytest.